# A value of type '...' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am getting the following error when I am adding a custom control via XAML. What can be the possible reason?

`A value of type '...' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'`

```
<Grid x:Name="QuantityDetail" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <GroupBox>
       .....
       <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LabelValue}">Min</Label>
       <!-- The following control -->
       <NumericUpDown></NumericUpDown>
       .....
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show how you have `IonNumericUpDow` defined?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Problem was that i was not referencing to one dll(which is referenced by numericupdown control) in my solution.
Actually NumericUpDown control is not my control, its present in different dll. And this control was refereing System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll. Now I am refereing it in my solution. And things are working

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the designer will use the DLLs referenced by the project for which it is representing a design. That means that this error often shows up when a solution is compiling and running perfectly - because a DLL that is referenced by a project further up the chain is present there, even if not in the project you're designing for. Typically those references are one or more of `PresentationCore`, `WindowsBase`, `System.Xaml`, or occasionally `WindowsFormsIntegration`, though.

Answer (score 8):

I had this intellise problem as well in our project (building was still possible), but not with an extern control. So maybe someone needs this answer...

The "problem" here was, that the UserControlXYZ.xaml was declared as <UserControl> but the UserControlXYZ.xaml.cs did not inherit from UserControl. So I had to add the UserControlXYZ **:UserControl** in xaml.cs (even though Resharper says base type is already specified and can be removed).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler claims that your control is not an `UIElement` (i doubt that it is lying), what does your control inherit from?

Comment: Problem solved now. actually NumericUpDown control is not my control, its present in different dll. And this control was refereing System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll. Now I am refereing it in my solution. And things are working.

Comment: but still not sure why do i need to add a reference to that dll. As I am not the one direcly using that dll. infact NumericUpDown(present in somebody's else dll) is using the System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll.

Comment: If the reference is not present in your application the external control simply would not work, it is **dependent** on it.

Comment: you mean i need to add all the dependencies of the external controls in my application? Not sure if that is required in all the cases. In that way if external control is refering some other external control then i need to add the dependencies of that control as well. And so on

Comment: That is how dependencies normally work (and why one should avoid unnecessary dependencies)

Comment: Actually HW, I'm going to call you on that.  You should only have to add references to dependencies which your code itself directly or indirectly references, not something that one of your dependencies depends on.  They take care of their own dependencies.  Think about it... the WPF DLLs that your project references reference an entire slew of others themselves which you don't have to reference in your project, unless you too reference a class deep within those dependencies.  In that case, yes, you would have to add them as well.

Comment: @MarqueIV: I am not sure if you need to reference the dependencies, but the respective DLLs have to be there in any case, and if those are not registered in the GAC, then you either need to copy them around in the build process or just add them as reference which usually comes with said build event already, right?