# Unable to add MediaPlayerElement in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to use the Windows.Media.Playback MediaPlayer. I am attempting to follow the information here [Play audio and video with MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer). I am able to hear the audio of a video by calling it from C#.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4-294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4"));
    mediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

However, when I attempt to add a `MediaPlayerElement` in XAML I get an `'MediaPlayerElement' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'1'.` error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"
             x:Class="XamarinTest.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <controls:MediaPlayerElement x:Name="_mediaPlayerElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="0"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

If I remove the `StackLayout` and have the `MediaPlayerElement` directly in the Content I get a `'Content' does not support values of type 'MediaPlayerElement'.`

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814627/the-value-of-type-cannot-be-added-to-a-collection-or-dictionary-of-type-u) so I assume I'm missing some kind of DLL or reference but I am unable to locate what reference would be needed.

Comment: you are trying to apply UWP controls to a cross platform Xamarin Forms project

Comment: So the control is for projects that are only UWP and cannot be used with Xamarin?

Comment: Yes, "Windows.Media.Playback" is only for Windows, and would not work on Android or iOS.  There are techniques you can use to include platform specific controls in a Xamarin project, or you can use a cross-platform control like [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement)

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer I'd accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to apply UWP controls to a cross platform Xamarin Forms project

`Windows.Media.Playback` is only for Windows, and would not work on Android or iOS. There are techniques you can use to include platform specific controls in a Xamarin project, or you can use a cross-platform control like [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement)